# Moving azure boards from one organisation to another

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I would like to know how to use/move azure boards with activity date to a different organisation project..

Comment: And what kind of trouble are you facing on?

Comment: Are you talking about boards themselves (i.e. the board configuration settings), or are you talking about work items?

Comment: I have a DevOps project in a organisation, now I have created a new organisation and a project where I want to move the work items from my old organisation project @Belegnar,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to moving work items from one organization to another, you can use the Excel to export and import the work items to achieve this .

First, you need to create a query to get work items, then install the `Azure DevOps Office Integration Tool` in azure devops , in Excel click on the `Team` button and then `New List` to get data from Azure DevOps to Excel, and finally publish work items to destination organization.

For detailed steps, please refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/medialesson/move-azure-devops-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another-42ad8370e46b).

In addition, another way is that you could think about using third party extension tool like the [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration#overview) . You can refer to this similar [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/513736/trying-to-move-boards-from-one-project-in-a-organi.html).

Comment: I've tried that but some of the column fields are missing in destination file and could not able to add a new column. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Also while publishing the work items, it only takes when it is in New state but not others like Active, Removed, Committed. 
Issue: Validation Error